# Idiomatic way to timeout TCP handshake in Go

Tags: tcp, go, timeout

What is the idiomatic way in Go to timeout a TCP conversation, such as initial protocol handshake? Let's say there is a goroutine that handles the TCP conversation. I can launch it, then launch a `time.After()`, then `select` for both of them and if timeout was hit, proceed on doing other stuff.

However, that means that the TCP goroutine will linger on after the timeout keeping the TCP connection alive even though nobody will ever need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To timeout the initial connection, you use `net.DialTimeout`, or more specifically, set the `Timeout` parameter on a [`net.Dialer`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dialer).

To timeout individual operations on a TCP connection while it's in use, you use [`SetDeadline`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn.SetDeadline), [`SetReadDeadline`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn.SetReadDeadline), or [`SetWriteDeadline`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn.SetWriteDeadline) on the connection.

If you need to cancel operations on a connection immediately, the way to do that in Go is to `Close()` the connection. Connections are safe for concurrent operations, and you can call `Close()` from a goroutine other than the one blocking on the network operation.